# Why does Microsoft recommend to use forEach instead of for .. in?

Tags: typescript, foreach

Recently I've switched from pure node.js to Typescript. In Microsoft's coding guidelines for Typescript they want their contributors to use `forEach` instead of loops. Literally everywhere I read that iterating with forEach is roughly 95% slower than iterating over a for loop.

Since a foreach loop looks much cleaner in most situations I wonder if they simply don't care about the performance (decision made in favour of readable code) or if there is another reason why I could forEach in Typescript?

Microsofts Coding Guidelines for Typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines

Comment: Arrays must not be iterated with `for-in` in the very first place.

Comment: Odd that they don't even mention [`for..of`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#forof-statements), which is probably the best option.

Comment: Hey @JohnnyHK seeing you commenting here, in the past I tried to contact you for a project but you don't provide any contact details in your SO profile. You may want to add that if you are looking for jobs. Thanks for your input, too.

Comment: @kentor Sorry, I've been all booked up for few years now so I haven't been looking for new work. Appreciate the interest, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally foreach is safer and is better for readability and maintainability.  Each element is read only and so cannot be modified.  It is also impossible to get index out of bounds exceptions.  However if performance is of particular concern you might find that a for loop is more appropriate.

Comment: Depending on the array size I need to iterate on I'd say it's actually significant what for loop to use. Actually I wished Typescript would convert my forEach loops into for loops for performance reasons, so that I have profit from both benefits :P.

Comment: Regarding performance, a `for ... in` is [generally slower](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/9) than a `forEach`.

Comment: Haven't tested with typescript but with raw jquery in chrome for loop performs better.  https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37  The little bit of googling I did suggested this is also the case with typescript.